# Capslock, Command, and Tab stopped working on bluetooth Mac OS keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard, bluetooth, wireless-keyboard

I have a travel-sized bluetooth keyboard with fresh batteries. I am using it to type out this question. It worked perfectly yesterday.

Today these no longer work:

- <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>
- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to toggle through my open apps
- Using <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through fields in an online form

Running Mac OS Mojave 10.14.1

**What I tried so far (to no success):**

- Restoring everything to factory defaults in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard > Import Sources - correctly set up
- System Prefs > Accessibility > Keyboard - Sticky not on, Slow keys not on.
- `killall Dock` in Terminal which killed the Dock and then replenished it
- Disconnected and reconnected keyboard
- Turned power off and then back on in keyboard
- Ran Disk Utility First Aid just in case
- Restarted Mac in single user mode

I can't think of anything else to do. No water damage since I've owned the keyboard (about 1 year). And in fact I normally keep some silicon packets on my electronics when not using them because I'm paranoid.

I do not like using F3 button because it requires an additional step to change to another app.

How can I restore their function?

Comment: Do other Command key combinations work? If so, what happens when you do Command+Tab+A? Does it select all as though you hadn't pressed Tab at all?

Comment: Yes, Command + Tab + A selects all. I can also do Command + ~ to toggle through different open windows in the same app (like my many open pages in Firefox).